# Breaking up or shortening long FOL statements

Tags: soft-question, notation, first-order-logic

Often, I recreationally create (somewhat-naïve) set theories of my own to contrast and compare with the big leagues (such as ZFC). In doing so, I realize I'm amazed that most axioms (even in their most formal form) seem to be quite short.

Regardless, I seem to find that many of my FOL statements, in order to have the properties I need, are very long.

As an example, here's one from tonight:

$$\forall A\forall B\forall a\Big[a\in A\implies \exists C\exists D\Big(\forall b(b\in B \iff a+b\in C)\wedge\forall d(d\in A\wedge d\not\equiv a\iff d\in D)\wedge A\cdot B = C+D\cdot B\Big)\Big]$$

Assuming that (logically speaking) this cannot be simplified, is there a relatively standard way of visually breaking up this one-liner nicely* into less of a monstrosity?

**By nicely, I mean without wrapping the text arbitarily.*

My initial thought was to introduce shorthand-condintionals such as

$$\forall A\forall B\forall a\Big[a\in A\implies \exists C\exists D\Big(\phi(C)\wedge\psi(D)\wedge A\cdot B = C+D\cdot B\Big)\Big]$$

Where $\phi, \psi$ can be defined elsewhere. But if $\phi, \psi$ are only used in this one instance, is that fine, or there alternatives?